"the girl with the red dress on" — What licenses the preposition "on"? What does it function as?
an example:
the girl with the red dress on
Is "on" a dangling/stranded preposition?
If it is, then what's its object?
What licenses "on"?
What does "on" function as?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

On here is an adverb (or adverb particle1 as Cambridge calls it):

ON: adverbin or into a position of being attached to or covering a surface
especially : in or into the condition of being worn

put his new shoes on 

(M-W)

It is basically licensed by the preposition with which shows possession or accompaniment (see M-W, senses 4a and 8a). The expression is:

have (got) something on
If you have clothes or shoes on, you are wearing them:

I loved that dress you had on last night.

(Cambridge)

So you can read:

the girl with the red dress on

as

the girl who has the red dress on

Cambridge confirms the same usage:

on adverb 
on your body or someone's body:

put something on: It's very cold so put a coat on.

nothing on: She wanders around the house with nothing on.

have something on: Can you remember what he had on (= was wearing)?

try something on: I tried on a few jackets, but none of them looked nice.



The example with nothing on is the closest to yours.
This related post about put something on, or put on something might help.

1 In modern grammar, a particle is a function word that must be associated with another word or phrase to impart meaning, i.e., it does not have its own lexical definition. (Wikipedia)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I would parse this sentence as follows:

The girl with the red dress on

In this context, the word "with" is equivalent to "who has". Both are specifiers which say the same thing about "the girl"; but "with" is shorter so it is more natural in conversational speech.

The girl who has the red dress on

Now the word "on" belongs with "has" to form the verb "have on":

Verb
have on (third-person singular simple present has on, present participle having on, simple past and past participle had on)

To be wearing.
She has on a nice red shirt and skinny jeans.


This verb is formed of two words, making it a phrasal verb:

In the traditional grammar of Modern English, a phrasal verb typically constitutes a single semantic unit consisting of a verb followed by a particle (examples: turn down, run into or sit up), sometimes collocated with a preposition (examples: get together with, run out of or feed off of).

So in this analysis, "on" is neither a preposition nor an adverb: it is a particle, one part of a verb which consists of two words. It's also acceptable for the verb's object to appear between the two words ─ i.e. in "has the red dress on", the object of the verb "has on" is "the red dress".
I think it makes sense to call "have on" a verb, rather than "on" occurring separately as an adverb (or a preposition with "herself" as the implied position), because the meaning of "have on" is not just the meaning of "have" modified by "on [herself]". The latter could mean the dress is folded up and balanced on her head, for instance, but the verb "have on" doesn't allow for that meaning. Hence the two words form a "single semantic unit" as described above.
Therefore, in the contracted form "with the red dress on", I would say that "on" is still a particle because it serves the same grammatical role as a part of the replaced verb "has on".

Of course, other grammatical analyses are possible. For instance, we could say that there are no two-word verbs in English and the word "on" is an adverb attached to the verb "have" (or the preposition "with"). However, I think this is a less useful analysis, because it requires such adverbs to have different meanings depending on which verb they're attached to. For example:

To "fold up" means to fold something compactly.
To "write up" means to document something officially.
To "drink up" means to drink something completely and now.

So it's syntactically possible to call "up" an adverb, but it doesn't have a clear or generalisable meaning as an adverb.
Even worse, consider "turn up", "turn down", "turn in" and "turn out": all have meanings which you don't really get by refining the meaning of the verb "turn" as an adverb normally would. So I think it makes more sense in such cases to say that both words together form one verb.

This is exactly my analysis. The debate about whether to consider this "on" a preposition or an adverb seems pointless to me.

I would personally say that "up" in those (fold up, write up, etc) could be an adverb of state-of-finality. While this isn't generalisable in all extant usage, I'd say it's productive, except in those cases where "up" or "down" would make more sense as a direction. (e.g. in "turn up" and "turn down" with regard to music are literal in their historic sense of turning a knob clockwise or anticlockwise - where an indicator on the left hand of a knob [at zero] - would be moving upwards or downwards - even "turn down" an invitation is really metaphor for turning over a physical invitation )

Yes, you can replace "with" with "who has" and get a sentence with the same meaning. But nothing follows about the syntactic structure; there's no reason to posit that "on" has the same function and part of speech in both cases.

So you think "with ... on" is a verb?

@Araucaria-Him No, nothing in my answer says that "with ... on" is a verb.

@alphabet The point is not merely that these two sentences have the same meaning, but that one is formed from the other by a standard replacement ("... who has ..." becomes "... with ...") which is typically made in conversational English. Since the replacement doesn't remove or alter the word "on", it has the same function in both sentences.

So in the verb "have on" is the present tense "she have ons" etc and the past "she have onned" and so forth? ;-) The reason I'm asking about "with ... on" is because 'particle' is a relational label like 'mother' or 'daughter', which in your analysis happens to be subsumed inside a verb containing another verb ("have"). So if "with ... on" is not a verb, what is "on" a particle to in your analysis? (i.e. 'who is it the sister of?')

@kaya3 That does not follow. You can usually replace one with another, preserving the meaning, but it doesn't mean that one is somehow "formed" from the other, or that the two have the same structure otherwise. Both include the word "on," but you haven't provided a reason to think it has the same part of speech or function in both cases.

@Araucaria-Him No, the present tense is "has on", the present participle is "having on", the past tense is "had on", and so on. This information is directly included in the quote from the dictionary. If you don't like Wiktionary for some reason then here's Collins, Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com... is this the first time you've ever learned of a phrasal verb?

@alphabet To me, your objection is as if we took the sentence "Abraham Lincoln was President of the United States of America", shortened it to "Abraham Lincoln was President of the USA", and then wondered whether the meaning or function of the word "President" had changed. Shortening "who has" to "with" should not change the meaning or function of other words in the sentence, and if you think otherwise then we just disagree.

@kaya3 In your example (with "the USA"), you're replacing one noun phrase with another. In this case, you're replacing one syntactic construction (a prepositional phrase with "with") with a completely different one (a relative clause with the verb "have").

@kaya3 You have ducked the question if what it's a participle of! If you have a problem explaining what it's a particle of when there's no verb and assume that the syntactic function of on is the same in both, then you have a problem. Because as it isn't a particle of anything in the with instance it thereby follows that it wasn't a particle in the verb instance either ;-)

@Araucaria-Him It's a part of the verb "have on". The other part is not present in the sentence, but is implied. Your objection to the concept of a phrasal verb is noted and I will file the note in the appropriate place.

I basically see what you are saying. I think I addressed it pretty clearly in my answer. "Y with an/a [whatever]" only exists because of the pre-existing idea of Y has an/a [whatever]. However, I don't think "have on" is  phrasal verb. It comes from have shoes on [her feet], gloves on [her hands]. her feet and her hands are not really needed so people stopped saying it most of the time.

@Lambie All phrasal verbs come from somewhere. All words do.

I don't think there's a phrasal verb here.

@Lambie I've linked to four dictionaries which say "have on" is a verb. I don't think there's a valid counterargument in your comments.

The question was about "the girl with the red dress on". which depends on: to have on a dress or to have a dress on. That's my whole point: no with without a previous have.

@Lambie That is not relevant, because the particle in a phrasal verb can often come after the object of the verb, as explained in my answer and on the linked Wikipedia page (here). The example usages given by the dictionaries also demonstrate this.

@Lambie I cannot infer any meaning from your comment, but whatever meaning it has doesn't contradict anything I've said. You're claiming that "have on" is not a phrasal verb. It is one, and you are offering no support for your position.

You can't be the person with the red dress on unless to have something on or to have on something exists. To say have something on [your feet, hands, head] requires logic, not proof.  That is called a separable phrasal verb. "infer meaning"? How about understand?

@Lambie Who on earth is saying "to have something on" doesn't exist? I said it is a phrasal verb, you said it isn't, now you are descending into nonsense. If I thought it didn't exist then I wouldn't link to four dictionaries which say it does, nor would I write an answer premised on the fact that it does. There is no need to continue.

NO, you don't get it: with the/a red dress on doesn't exist without the existence of: to have a red dress on. That's the whole point.  You have to go beyong the phrasal verb to explain: with a red dress on.

@Lambie There is no need to summarise my answer for me; I wrote it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

On is always a preposition plain and simple.
Yes, most dictionaries repeat the outdated analysis that any preposition that doesn't have a complement automatically turns into an adverb, but that doesn't pan out with the way other parts of speech are analyzed: verbs don't magically turn into another part of speech if they lack a complement, neither do adjectives or nouns for that matter. Prepositions resemble verbs in that they can take a wide range of complements: no complement, an object noun phrase, an adjective phrase, a preposition phrase, or various clause types.
Now, here on is licensed by with in combination with its object noun phrase - it could hardly appear without some appropriate NP designating a clothing item or similar - it is a locative complement in the prepositional phrase with the red dress on. This type of prepositional phrase can be used independently in clause structure and in phrase structure:

With the red dress on, she walked out the door.
With the red dress on the floor, she walked out the door.
With the red dress under her arm, she walked out the door.
With the red dress over her head, she walked out the door.

Note that in the exact same place, other prepositions (with object NPs) can be substituted.

fev's answer explains how this relates to other uses of on, but to fully understand the picture here, I think it's also useful to consider how it relates to other uses of with. It is a fairly general pattern that with — like have — can take a noun phrase complement plus a predicative complement:

"the man with the quizzical look on his face"

Note: in this example, it would also be valid to interpret "on his face" as directly modifying "look"; compare "I didn't understand the quizzical look on his face." The same is true of some, but not all, of the other examples below.


"the house with the flamingo sculpture out front"
"a professional with eight years of experience under her belt"
"children with parents in the armed forces"
"With half of her teammates on vacation, she found herself with more work to do and less time to do it in."
"With that taken care of, he turned to other matters."
"With my brother away at camp and my best friend not speaking to me, it was going to be a difficult summer."


As others have noted, "on" here is an adverb and not a preposition.
It is necessary in the sentence to distinguish between simple possession and actually wearing. If I say, "Sally has a red dress", she may or may not be wearing it right now. I'm just saying that she owns such a dress or has it in her possession. But if I say, "Sally has a red dress on", I mean she is wearing it right now.
"On" can also be a preposition conveying the same idea. Like one might say, "Mary is wearing the green dress. The red dress is on Sally." In that case the object of the preposition is clearly "Sally". But in the sentence, "Sally has a red dress on", "on" doesn't work as a preposition because, as you say, it has no object. "Sally" is not the object of "on" because "Sally" is the subject of the sentence. But we commonly use "on" as an adverb, usually modifying "has", to indicate a person is wearing a piece of clothing. "Bob has an ugly hat on", etc.

It could be viewed as a preposition with object elided: "Sally has the red dress on [her]". Maybe that's how this sense originated.

Sally is wearing a red dress on HER BODY. The object is Sally's body.

@stackoverblown "Sally is wearing a dress" It goes without saying it is on her body.  We do not normally say "Sally is wearing a dress on" it sounds redundant and unnatural. Compare 1. "I'm wearing a hat", 2. "I never wear hats but today I am wearing one” here the  pronoun "one" stands for "hat". Do I need to add "on my head" for 1 and 2?  What about, 3. "I have a beautiful green hat” and 4. "Now, I have a beautiful green hat on” No.3 is about possession while 4. is telling the listener what is the thing on their head.

I suppose in that case "on" is a preposition, or maybe it's a pronoun standing for "on my head"?

@Mari-LouA In your last example I'd say it's still an adverb modifying "have". "I have ... on".

@barmar RE origination: Could be. I haven't studied the history. Did English speakers many years ago say, "I have a red shirt ON ME" or "ON MY BODY"? I don't know.

@stackoverblown Except the catch is, the words "her body" do not appear in the sentence. One could argue that "on" is a preposition with the object left out. Of course in practice it doesn't matter as long as people know what you mean. :-)

@Jay I don't know early English, but French tends to use lots of reflexive pronouns where modern English leaves them understood.

If you believe Huddleston & Pullum, on here is an intransitive preposition, one that doesn't take an object.

@alphabet I must admit I've never heard of an "intransitive preposition" before. That sounds like a paradox. In this case, if you want to call "on" a preposition, you can't say that it doesn't have an object. Rather, you have to say that the object is elided or assumed. The object is "herself" or "her body", but that's not stated. It's not that the dress is on nothing. If the dress is in a drawer on nothing, then we wouldn't say, "She has the dress on".

@Jay On H&P's approach, on can be either transitive or intransitive, just like the verb to eat. There are also some prepositions, like there, that can only be intransitive; we call them prepositions, not adverbs, because they behave syntactically like transitive prepositions.

@Jay Intransitive prepositions are over 100 years old!

@alphabet Hmm, this is a fascinating concept. "To eat" can be transitive because we may or may not specify what you are eating, or the thing being eaten may be irrelevant in context. For example, if I say, "Humans need to eat to live", "to eat" is intransitive because I am not saying that they need to eat a specific thing, but that just in general, they need to eat. For "on" to be intransitive in this sense, you'd have to say that what the subject is on is irrelevant or unspecified. But in the sentence, "Sally as a red dress on", what the dress is on is certainly not unspecified ...

... It is on Sally. I suppose you could assert than an "intransitive preposition" is a very different thing from an intransitive verb and just doesn't work the same way.

@Araucaria-Him Umm, okay. To assert that an idea was first proposed over 100 years ago tells us nothing about whether or not it is true. The idea of a flat earth has been around for thousands of years. :-)

@Jay Yes, but the dumb flat-earth idea was superseded by the far superior round earth idea. Same applies here. ;-)

There are two issues: one is that you can't point out a person or thing as being with something unless that person or thing can have the thing.  The girl with the red dress on exists because The girl has a red dress on.  The man with a/the boat is the man who has a boat. The other issue is: to have something on, be dressed in it, presupposes: on her body, on their feet, on their head or hands. Etc. The two work together. First the have verb and second the elipted part(s) of the body which obviously were dropped over time.

@lambie Maybe. One would have to study the historical etymology to see if "on" (in this sense) used to have an object that came to be elided over time. I don't think it's essential. It is common, for example, to say, "I put the clothes away" without specify where you put them.

@Jay The reason why the on's were dropped is probably because of redundancy. He had gloves on [his hands] is generally understood not to be on feet. Ergo, it's not needed. Except in sentences like: He had a sock on this head.

@Lambie Plausible hypothesis. But "plausible hypothesis" is a long way from "proven fact". I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm saying that I don't know, and I don't think you actually know either. You're just making stuff up. :-)

No, Jay, linguists generate examples based on their internalized structures. It is not making stuff up. Structural grammaticality is traditionally understood as intuitive, the result of
an internal sense of grammar and functionally independent of other aspects of language, such as
semantics and sociolinguistics(Chomsky 1965). Sorry lost the link, a paper. But I think it is learned, not innate.

to have something
to have a car, to have a dog, to have anything at all.
I have a car.
The person with a car, a dog, etc. The with refers back to the idea of have. If you have not "had it", you cannot be the one "with it".
To have something on
Idiom:
If you have clothes or shoes on, you are wearing them:
I loved that dress you had on last night.
Cambridge Dictionary
To have something on =
To be dressed in something or to be wearing something.
What licenses "on" is the idiom that is not there in full.
The girl who has the red dress on.
AKA: The girl with the red dress on.
ALSO:
If the girl has the red dress on, she is the girl with the red dress. You can't get to "with the dress on" without going through the idiom with have.
Try any phrase with with, and somewhere there is a have. The house has open windows. The house with open windows.
The girl dressed in a red dress.
The girl wearing a red dress.
on is part of the idiom: to have something on: on your body, head, feet or hands
He has gloves on [his hands].
She has boots on [her feet].
They have trousers on [their bodies].
We have our hats on [our heads].
on can be called a preposition here but unless you know the idiom, you are not going to get very far with them. The clothes are on [their bodies, or hands or heads or feet, implied]. on=preposition.  So, does it matter? It matters whether or not you use the idiom correctly. You wouldn't be using it correctly if you said: They on have their clothes.
Furthermore, it is separable: They have their clothes on. OR They have on their clothes.
Merriam Webster:
: an expression in the usage of a language that is peculiar to itself either in having a meaning that cannot be derived from the conjoined meanings of its elements (such as up in the air for "undecided") or in its grammatically atypical use of words (such as give way)
Oh, and one can also have things off:
The boys with their shoes off.
The ladies with their wigs off.
The man with his shoes off.
[Apologies to Araucaria=Him for using a dictionary to explain what an idiom is.]

This usage is licensed by a simple definition.

(OLD) on adverb
on somebody’s body; being worn

Put your coat on.
I didn't have my glasses on.
What did she have on (= what was she wearing)?



So the whatever 'on' = a prepositional phrase 'on someone's body'?

@EdwinAshworth Rather, "< whatever > on"= the construction "< whatever > + 'placed on' the implied part of body of the person implied by the context".  Sometimes the implied part has no obvious name (glasses, on the nose?), but more often, I think, it does (hat - keep(s) it on - placed on your/their/our/… head).

It would be useful to give info in the answer such as part of speech. Links rot.

Another interpretation here - though I find the previous ones convincing enough.
the girl with the red dress on
means
the girl with the red dress on her(self)
In a sense, on is licenced by the subject, i.e. girl, in this case as there is no other object in the phrase to cause ambiguity.
If it were instead
the girl with the red dress on cycled through Oxford carefree as a springtime sparrow
there might be a possibility that the phrase meant that
the girl with the red dress on her bicycle (carrier) cycled through Oxford carefree as a springtime sparrow

To explain it simply, "on" functions as indicating that she is wearing the red dress.
If the word was not there, the sentence would be "the girl with the red dress", which could either mean a) she has (as in "owns" or is in possession of) the red dress; or b) she is actually wearing the red dress.
While I am not 100% familiar with the meaning of a dangling/stranded preposition for an object, I would assume the object is "dress". Just the noun "dress", not "red dress" or "the red dress".

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

What licenses this is a particular sense of the adverb on. It is not the verb have or be or even the preposition with that does so. The OED says that this sense of the adverb on dates from Old English. This is what they givepaywalled link for sense 6 of this adverb:


In the position of being attached to or covering a surface, esp. the body, as clothing, hair, etc.


They give a great many citations both early and late. These include citations with other verbs than have as well as examples using with that are not associated with a particular verb.
To show you that this is part of the adverb, here is a small sub-selection from among their many citations that should illustrate these properties. In each quote below, do look carefully at exactly how the word on is used. (And please have patience with the original spellings in the earlier examples.)


a1425 (?a1400) Largesse hadde on a robe fresh.  ―G. Chaucer, Romaunt of Rose (Hunterian MS.) 1187
c1480 (a1400) He gert dispoile hir..of al þe clathis scho one had.  ―St. Juliana 12 in W. M. Metcalfe, Legends of Saints in Scottish Dialect (1896) vol. II. 424
a1500 (?c1450) Thei..hadde on hattes of stile.  ―Merlin 191
1560 If you send 100 of them [sc. seal skins] tawed with the haire on, they will bee solde, or else not.  ―Letter in R. Hakluyt, Principal Navigations (1598) vol. I. 307
1570 To weare a linnen Ephod on. ―B. Googe, translation of T. Kirchmeyer, Popish Kingdome ii. f. 26
1597 O let me thinke on Hastings and be gone To Brecnock while my fearefull head is on.  ―W. Shakespeare, Richard III iv. ii. 125
a1616 You crow Cock, with your combe on.  ―W. Shakespeare, Cymbeline (1623) ii. i. 24
1645 Then to the well-trod stage anon, If Jonsons learned Sock be on.  ―J. Milton, L’Allegro in Poems 36
1813 He received the donors with his hat on, while seated under the half-tester of a wretched bed.  ―T. Dibdin, Metrical History of England vol. II. xii. 198 (note)
1902 Your idea of a happy life is always to do the disagreeable thing; mine is to gather the roses―with the gloves on, so that the thorns should not prick me.  —W. S. Maugham, Mrs. Craddock v. 46
1936 My red silk dressing-gown on, tied tightly.  ―R. Lehmann, Weather in Streets ii. 173
2001 He walked right up to the lake as if he planned to walk right into the water with his twills and his wool shirt on.  ―C. Cooke, Bostons 158


As you see, the licenture derives solely from this particular sense for the adverb. It is not dependent on other verbs nor on other prepositions.

Just about anything can be with [something]. However, for the "with" to have meaning with on to mean to be dressed in that, there must be a underlying assumption of the idiom: to have something on. Just because the verb have is not there doesn't mean it is not operant sub rosa. Also, to be on, as a head, for example, is not the same meaning. Also, the dressing gown is elided for: dressing gown [was] on

Isn't this  adverb:4 / preposition: 2 / particle but adv: 1 / particle and essentially neither: 1 (ignoring less credible answers)?

Consider the following...

"the girl with the red dress on"


"the man with the silly hat"


"a student with get-up-and-go"

In each case 'with' is an idiomatic alternative for 'who has'.
The 'licence' for the preposition "on" is that it is understood as being part of a common phrasal verb
to have (a piece of clothing) on
As such, and in common with many other phrasal verbs, the preposition is not necessarily meaningful except as a part of the whole.

But 'the girl with the red dress on' doesn't have a verb.

@EdwinAshworth - a very good point!  I've re-worked my answer.

@Lambie - yes I realised too late that there are several of us making a similar point!

No worries. I just don't see why folks don't see that if there is with an/a/the or null word that it has to be have or a stand-in for have.

on is licensed by dress.
on is an adjective.
Keep your mind open.

She's the girl with the red dress on.
It's the house with the garage door open.


I'm surprised there's only one downvote, but not surprised that it's anonymous.

It would help your case if you could provide any evidence that on is an adjective here, and even better if you included citations and references for this position. Why would it follow the entire noun phrase “the red dress” rather than show up in the normal position for adjectives somewhere between the determiner the and the head-noun dress? What would “the on red dress” or “the red on dress” mean? While English does have a few postpositive adjectives that can or must follow their head-noun, examples galore you will not find—and this doesn’t seem like one of those.

@tchrist I think it is possible to analyze "on/off" and "closed/open"  and "up/down" etc as ungradable adjectives of state, and  that the state is being predicated of the preceding noun. "It's the house with the light on" or "It's the house with the garage door open"  or "She's the one with the hat on" or "He's the one with his hat off".  The preceding noun licenses the particular ungradable adjective: "He's the one with his hat open"  uses an unlicensed adjective of state, and is a no-go, but "He's the one with his fly open" is OK.  "It's the car with driver-side front window down".

@TimR All you're noticing is that the copula is omissible in "with clauses. It does not make the PC or Locative Complement and adjective. Why should it?

@Araucara:  with-clauses have an implied copula and on can therefore be understood as a "predicate adjective" predicated of "dress".

Whatever it is, it is a binary state, on/off.  She's the one dancing with her shoes off.  That's why I'm tending away from "locative".

Oops "an adjective" not "and adjective"

The quotation in context is:

See the girl with the red dress on//
She can do the birdland all night long//
...

This is from the song What'd say by Ray Charles, released in 1959. The lyrics were put together for (rough) scansion and rhyme, not to conform with grammatically standard English.

Are you saying that "the girl with the red dress on" is not grammatically standard English?

Yes. Although not exactly ungrammatical, it isn't natural English. “The girl in the red dress” would be the normal phrasing here.

I'm sorry but See the girl with the red dress on? is 100% standard. See the man with his clothes off? Standing in the dressing room?
